# How do I access the out message in camel using a RouteBuilder?

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel, so I apologise if this is a stupid question.

I have implemented a class that extends `RouteBuilder` to take a file from the file system and use the contents to dynamically invoke a webhook. However, I cannot work out how to inspect the result of invoking the target webhook. I assumed that it would be available in the `out` message of the message exchange... but I cannot work out how to access this.

The basic implementation is as follows:

public class WebhookRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    final String messageSource = "/tmp/messages/webhook";

    from(messageSource)
        .log("Received message: ${body}")
        .process(new WebhookProcessor())
        .log("Invoking webhook with headers: ${headers}")
        .log("Invoking webhook with body: ${body}")
        .toD("${header." + HTTP_URI + "}")
        .end();
}

protected class WebhookProcessor implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        try {
            Message message = exchange.getIn();
            JsonNode json = JacksonUtils.getObjectMapper().readTree(message.getBody(String.class));

            // Set the target URL, method and content type
            message.setHeader(HTTP_URI, json.get("targetUrl").asText());
            message.setHeader(HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
            message.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, json.get("contentType").asText());
            final String username = json.get("username").asText();
            final String password = json.get("password").asText();
            if (username != null && password != null) {
                String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s", username, password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                message.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Basic %s", encodedAuth));
            }
            message.setBody(json.get("body").asText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I can then make use of this RouteBuilder elsewhere in my application, as follows:

```
private static CamelContext camel;
private static ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

...

    if (camel == null) {
        camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camel.addRoutes(new WebhookRouteBuilder());
        producerTemplate = camel.createProducerTemplate();
        camel.start();
    }

    // Convert the webhook to a JSON string
    final String webhookJson = JacksonUtils.getObjectMapper()
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(webhook);

    Object result = producerTemplate.requestBody(WEBHOOK_MESSAGE_SOURCE, webhookJson);
```

With this code, the result object is simply a string whose value is the same JSON that I passed into the requestBody method. However, I am looking for a way to access the `Exchange` and retrieve the `out` message.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think this might help you, https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: @Andre I am afraid that I had already read over the page that you referenced and I am not sure that it helps. The code that I have already modifies the IN message to set the properties that are required before routing the message to the HTTP component using the `toD` method.

My expectation is that the HTTP component would create an OUT message in the Exchange populated with the results of invoking the HTTP endpoint. However, I need to know how to access the Exchange and inspect the OUT message.

Comment: In your route definition, you can create a process to manipulate/validate the out or in objects.  `.process(exchange -> { exchange.getIn(); exchange.getMessage().setBody(); }` 
Note: getOut is deprecated, you should use getMessage.